# IntelliJ IDEA new project default to Java 1.6 (Java 1.8 is set in Default Project Settings)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My "Project JDK" and "Project language level" is set to 1.8 in Default Project Settings. Still, when I create a new project "language level" defaults to "6":
https://www.screencast.com/t/hZDDdaZZ1JNd

Comment: Are you using maven? Then you can override this in the pom. Or, if you are creating many maven projects, share a parent pom and define it there. Then your default is always 1.8

Comment: I don't think I do. I've checked default Maven settings, they seem to use 1.8 as well https://www.screencast.com/t/tliG7Kisa7

Comment: There is a bug when configured default language level is not used if project is created from the template (Command Line App in your case): [IDEA-123363](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123363).

Comment: What version of Intellij Idea are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I've just upgraded to version 2017.3.4 (build from January, 30) and the problem still persists

Comment: +1 for providing a video which clearly shows that you are hitting the bug Andrey identified in the comment above. I can reproduce it. It seems amazing that the bug has remained open for over 3 years.

Comment: @Andrey You should post your comment as an answer since you have identified the problem.